# ms-excel: bubble trouble - creating amazing looking charts

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MS Excel: Bubble trouble - creating amazing looking charts](https://superuser.com/questions/84785/ms-excel-bubble-trouble-creating-amazing-looking-charts)

i am reading this article:

http://www.juiceanalytics.com/writing/bubble-trouble/

i would like to make a chart that looks like this in excel.

[image]

is vba a requirement?

can anyone help me to start?

Answer (score 1):

If you read the article, the whole point was that they couldn't get Excel to do charts this nice. The Nodebox script they used is given, and it's a pretty nice bit of software to use.

Answer (score 0):

Excel has a native bubble chart type. The rest is just manipulating the source data and chart formatting.

Comment: It will help if you explain HOW to do so :-)